# How can you quickly view a variable type in Xcode and Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoa-touch, closures

For example, if I'm inside a closure and I say,

```
... { response, data, error in 
...
}
```

Is there a way for me to view the types of response, data, and error very quickly?

Right now, the only way I can do this without doing a println and building my code is saying

```
var test = response as! Int
```

or a ridiculous downcast that's obviously going to display as an error. I look and see it says, "NSURLResponse is not convertible to type int" and that way I know. But this is really inefficient. Is there any way to do this at all in Xcode, even if it isn't specifically a closure and you just want to see the type of the variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Alt-click` on the variable does the thing in my case most of the time.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks Anton!